# Using a method in multiple classes

Tags: php, oop

I have a specific method that is used in multiple classes.The problem here is that if i want to do changes in the method , I need to replicate that in other classes as well.How can i fix this ?

Comment: Extend the base class containing the method? Or make it static, so its callable everywhere, if the class is loaded obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". And in this case it depends on the purpose of the method, the design of your application, and such like.

One approach is - as Mahfuzel points out - is to use a trait:

```
<?php

class MyClass {
    use MyTrait;
}


trait MyTrait {

    public function greeter($name){
        echo "Hello $name";
    }
}


$myObj = new MyClass();
$myObj->greeter("user2650277"); // Hello user2650277
```

This basically does a "dumb" import of the trait's code into your class. I'd use this as kinda of an "interface implementation" in a class: a trait defines a specific additional behaviour your class needs. If your method can be considered like that, then traits are easy.

If your method is just a helper function, then perhaps stick it in its own class, and make it static:

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    public function myMethod($name){
        MyOtherClass::greeter($name);
    }

}

class MyOtherClass {

    public static function greeter($name){
        echo "Hello $name";
    }
}

$myObj = new MyClass();
$myObj->myMethod("user2650277"); // Hello user2650277
```

Or perhaps your method has state of its own, and should simply be a method of that class, not a static function:

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    public function myMethod($name){
        $otherClass = new MyOtherClass($name);
        $otherClass->greeter();
    }

}

class MyOtherClass {

    private $name;

    public function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function greeter(){
        echo "Hello {$this->name}";
    }
}

$myObj = new MyClass();
$myObj->myMethod("user2650277"); // Hello user2650277
```

(obviously you might want to use dependency injection rather than just creating that instance of `MyOtherClass` directly in the code of `MyClass`, but that's kinda outwith the scope of your question).

I have purposely not included another option here: creating a base class, hoisting the method up into that, and making MyClass (and your other classes that need the function) extend that. That's almost certainly going to be the wrong approach, as it's unlikely the inheritance hierarchy will fulfil the "MyClass IS A MyBaseClass" which it *must* do if you're using inheritance. MyClass does not simply become a subclass of another in a design sense simply because it wants to use a method of the potential base class. That's poor OO. In general stick to the addage "favour composition over inheritance", which all the options above do.

Don't simply pick the easiest solution to type in... think about the architecture of your app, and implement the appropriate solution.

Let me know if you need anything clarified.

Answer (score 2):

According to your question it seems you are looking for a smart way of code use in multiple classes. I think `Traits` can be good choice for you. You can find details in php official doc: [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

> Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages
>   such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single
>   inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in
>   several independent classes living in different class hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Having experience with traits on a big project, I would advise to be very cautious of them and to use them wisely. Trait clashes are not a very pleasant experience.

Therefore I would tend to using static methods, inheritance and even code duplication over traits, though the latter are indeed very useful for specific purposes.

From the sound of it, making the function [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) would solve your problem.